# Hyper V SMB share kills the network

Tags: hyper-v

We have 4 Hyper V VM installations on 2 HP DL 380 G8 servers and have they are connected to HP NSA 2040 SAN Storage through 6 Gbps Fibre channel. The physical machines are clustered.

Out of the 4, 2 are Clustered Hyper V's running Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3 and we have 2 Clustered Hyper V for Database server running MS SQL 2012 R2.

The issue here is that the APP servers are slow in communicating with the DB server. The Hyper V's have a dedicated 4 * 1Gbps interface cards teamed and the packets are getting timed out. But from any other machine in the subnet the communications are proper.

When ever i try to copy a file from the DB server to the APP server using SMB share it kills my network, the copy will happen but after the copy is completed the network comes backup.

Its strange scenario. APP server 2 APP server smb copy is fine, and from DB to DB smb copy is fine but cannot copy between them.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Sriram A Das

Comment: If you dedicate a NIC to each VM, does the symptom is there ? As I seen you got 4 VM & 4 NIC

Comment: Hi We have 2 Physical server, one server rune 2 VMs and Hyper V's are using teamed ( 4 NICs ) to communicate with the network.

Comment: I mean, without QoS (check if all server got it enabled too), SMB can load all the available bandwidth. If it's teamed on the four NIC, it can be the issue. Why I told to separate the NIC allocation to the VM

Comment: Hi i have separated the NICs.. but still the same issue is there.The files are being transfered at 80 MBps max.

Comment: Does it still kill the network ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things to check for:

- **HP Service Pack**: start with this, it will update the NICs drivers and firmware, the problem could be there? http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx
- **RAM?**: no kidding, some of my clients problem with the SMB performance turned out to be a RAM problem, since you're using G8 server, those should be fitted with good spect, but is it that you don't have enough RAM on the VMs or the host?
- **Teaming**: how is it done? using the Windows built in tools in service manager (Windows 2012), or using the HP Proliant Network Configuration Utility (Windows 2008 R2)? the NCU caused me more troubles than I would like to admit, if I were you I'd take a look on both and check for any error logs or misconfiguration.
- **Switches**: Are your switches managed full NIC capable? running latest firmware? some switches will work better if you create a "Link Aggregation" on them, give that a try if your switches support it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation
- **SMB Multichannel**: using all 4 cards in a single team? take 2 out of those in a dedicated team for SMB alone: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emberger/archive/2014/09/15/force-network-traffic-through-a-specific-nic-with-smb-multichannel.aspx

Hope you find your answer in one of these solutions.

Comment: Hi this is a brand new installation with all of the drivers updated. We took out the team and assigned a dedicated NIC to each VM but still we have the same issue. The host has 256 GB RAM and the clients are assigned just 60 GB that shouldn't be an issue.